# How can I make my .htaccess force https but only for one directory (whilst keeping ExpressionEngine, and no-www based rules)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, expressionengine

I've read lots of questions on this general topic on SO but can't seem to get a solution that solves my issue.

We're using ExpressionEngine and need to only have *one* section behind https:// We want the rest of the website to redirect any https:// request to http://.

Example #1:
**http:**//test.com/facebook 301 redirect to **https:**//test.com/facebook

Example #2:
**https:**//test.com/test_page/ 301 redirect to **http:**//test.com/test_page/

**Note:** /facebook is not a directory on the server, it is a template group inside ExpressionEngine

Here is my .htacess so far:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Force SSL on facebook pages
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/facebook
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%2/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

# Remove SSL on other pages
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/facebook
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]

# Remove www. from URLs
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Magic ExpressionEngine rule to remove index.php requirement from URLs    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**The current problem:**
Example #2 works fine, and URLs with https:// are getting the https:// removed.

But if you go to http://test.com/facebook, it redirects to **http:**//test.com/**index.php**/facebook. i.e. no HTTPS and the addition of index.php.

We think that the .htaccess file is being run twice, the first time it is hitting the first block and getting redirected, but then it gets 'index.php' added to it, and hits the second block, therefore removing the https://.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Thanks!

**Live HTTP Headers report**

```
http://test.com/facebook/register

GET /facebook/register HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 20 Dec 2012 17:20:17 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: https://test.com/facebook/register

--------

http://test.com/index.php/facebook/register

GET /index.php/facebook/register HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 20 Dec 2012 17:20:17 GMT
Server: Apache
```

Comment: Rob, FYI... for future EE specific questions that fit, you can post to the EE StackExchange site: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com

Comment: Could you show the http-headers sent?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` This is a stricter check than simply `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on`. This is probably not the cause of the issue but just to rule things out...

Comment: @AnnaBrown_MediaGirl I would've but I thought the problem is more .htaccess related than EE related

Comment: Totally agree. Just making sure you knew about the EE site.

Comment: @Gerben I just installed Live HTTP headers for Firefox and added the important bits to the ticket, does that help at all?

Comment: I checked this post last night and there were 2 additional answers, one with lots of helpful detail. For some reason they have been removed, is there a way to see these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the facebook page is also created by EE. Now it makes sense. The url `http://example.com/facebook` is redirect to the https version. Then it is rewritten to the EE url `/index.php/facebook`, and it no longer matches `^/facebook` so it is again redirected to `http://example.com/index.php/facebook`

This could e.g. be fixed by using the following.

```
# Remove SSL on other pages
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/facebook
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php/facebook
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi @Gerben , I tried that and when I visit http://test.com/facebook it redirects to https://test.com/index.php/facebook which is closer to the correct URL, but still has that index.php and I get this error in chrome: Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.

Comment: Also, if I go to https://test.com/facebook it redirects me to **http://**test.com/facebook

Comment: Sorry. The rewriteCond should have been added to the remove-ssl part of you code. See my edit above for the new code. Hope it works for you.

Comment: That seems to have worked! I also had to add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/assets` for the shared CSS/JS but it all looks great. Thankyou for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This conditional isn't working as you expect it to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/facebook
```

I believe REQUEST_URI is actually /index.php/facebook, not /facebook. As such, any request for https:// will be redirected to http://.

Comment: Unfortunately if you change that line to !^/index.php/facebook it's even worse! (redirect loop)